# Application Pool - Enable 32-bit application = false generating stack overflow error

Tags: iis, stack-overflow, 32bit-64bit, wow64, syswow64

If set it True - IIS > Application Pools > DefaultApplicationPool > Enable32BitApplication then application working fine.
But, if set it False then application running but after logging, it showing StackOverflowException.

.Net FrameWork: 4.0

Why its running properly on 32bit-true and getting failed to run making -false?
Is it sufficient information? i can provide more if  require.

I tried lots of solution to resolve - FrameWork Registration, ISAP, Handler, ISAP-CGi restriction, buid application on x64 but it not resolving.

Oberservation: When i looked into process explore then its loding dll from SYSWOW64.

Can you please help then it would be great for us.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue recently, due to a change we introduced significantly increased the number of methods that were called in some auto-generated code that was data-driven, and coincidentally the data driving the code generation was increased significantly.

Our customer was experiencing the same issue running our component under IIS with Enable32BitApplication set to false.

Turns out the default stack size for threads created by IIS on 2008R2 and later now is now smaller.  See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/932909/by-default-the-maximum-stack-size-of-a-thread-that-is-created-in-a-nat

We were able to fix the issue by having our code explicitly create a thread with a stack size of 1MB (which is the default for outside of IIS).  Our component is written in C#/.NET.

If you are unable to change the stack size programmatically, you may still be able to use `editbin` as described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tom/2008/03/31/stack-sizes-in-iis-affects-asp-net/